# Coordinating model training and model use

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework-2.4, apache-spark-mllib

I've been tasked with implementing a content recommendation microservice, and have chosen to do so with [Apache Spark's MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/mllib/) sitting atop a Play server.

Current architecture:

- A server instance running Play for responding to model queries
- A separate instance running its own Spark context (daily?) to train and retrain the model

I've chosen to use separate instances, as it seems I can't use Spark streaming with the particular MLlib algorithm I'm using, and I want to keep the CPU load light for the query server.

**Questions:**

1. How do I move the trained model to the query server?
2. What's a good way to automate retraining? (Cron job? Akka scheduler?)

Comment: Did you find answer for your second question?

Comment: I ended up added a timestamp to a Wrapper object around a trained model. When 24 hours have passed, I prompt the system to train again. It checks if the time has passed on every request. Probably not ideal.